# how to import gmail contacts to enigmail?

Tags: linux, fedora, enigmail

$ rpm -qa | grep -i "^thunderbird"
thunderbird-enigmail-1.1.2-1.fc14.i686
thunderbird-3.1.7-2.fc14.i686
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 14 (Laughlin)
Release:    14
Codename:   Laughlin
$ 

I just can't import my contacts to the address book of enigmail.

Does anyone has any links/howtos please? 

Thank you!

Comment: enigmail is the encryption plugin of thunderbird, right? so you want to import google-contacts into your thunderbird, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enigmail doesn't have an "address book" like Thunderbird does. It's only a wrapper around GnuPG encryption software, and only stores *keys*, not contacts.